# parted mktable error. but gparted "create partition table" works?

Tags: command-line, partitioning

I am trying to automate formatting of USB drives. 
What I do is:

1. Unmount USB drive
2. terminal: sudo parted /dev/sdb1 mktable msdos

This is when I get the following error:

```
Error: Partition(s) 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17,
18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37,
38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57,
58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64 on /dev/sdb1 have been written, but we have been
unable to inform the kernel of the change, probably because it/they are in use.
As a result, the old partition(s) will remain in use.  You should reboot now
before making further changes.
```

When I create a partition table on the same USB stick in GParted I don't have to reboot!

What do I have to enter into the terminal so I don't have to reboot? I mean GParted is simply the GUI to parted right?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, it looks like you're trying to create a partition table, on a partition
`/dev/sdb1`
instead of on the disk itself
`/dev/sdb`

I'm guessing that could lead to some strange errors... are you really trying to create 64 partitions on a USB drive, or that could be a strange error.

After sorting out the partition table, I think these commands should work:

1. Create MBR (msdos) partition table

   ```
   sudo parted /dev/sdb mktable msdos
   ```
2. Make a partition (a primary partition, with FS ID ext3, starting at 1MB & using 100% of space) (If start at 0% or 0MB, it's not aligned to MB's and complains):

   ```
   sudo parted /dev/sdb mkpart primary ext3 1 100%
   ```
3. Apparently `gparted` does a `wipefs` on new or existing partitions when they're formatted, to avoid problems with old filesystem signatures. So could do  this too:

   ```
   sudo wipefs -a /dev/sdb1
   ```
4. Then make the filesystem on the first partition (sdb1) just created (`-L` label is optional, see the mkfs.ext3/mke2fs man page for lots of options):

   ```
   sudo mkfs.ext3 -L "NewLabel" /dev/sdb1
   ```

Here's the built-in help from `parted <dummydevicefile> help mkpart` (seems more detailed than the man/info page):

```
mkpart PART-TYPE [FS-TYPE] START END     make a partition

    PART-TYPE is one of: primary, logical, extended  
    FS-TYPE is one of: zfs, btrfs, ext4, ext3, ext2, fat32, fat16, hfsx,
    hfs+, hfs, jfs, swsusp, linux-swap(v1), linux-swap(v0), ntfs, reiserfs,
    freebsd-ufs, hp-ufs, sun-ufs, xfs, apfs2, apfs1, asfs, amufs5, amufs4,
    amufs3, amufs2, amufs1, amufs0, amufs, affs7, affs6, affs5, affs4,
    affs3, affs2, affs1, affs0, linux-swap, linux-swap(new),
    linux-swap(old)
    START and END are disk locations, such as 4GB or 10%.  Negative values
    count from the end of the disk.  For example, -1s specifies exactly the
    last sector.

    'mkpart' makes a partition without creating a new file system on the
    partition.  FS-TYPE may be specified to set an appropriate partition
    ID.
```

Comment: Thats it, thanks a lot! Could you please help me out with the additional steps I have to take to create one partition with an ext3 filesystem that spans the whole USB drive?

Comment: I always use `gparted`, but it uses the `parted` libraries so it's like a gui front end... and it has a "view output" (or similar) that lets you see the results of commands it uses, I *think* it shows the commands themselves too, so try using it and see if it tells you what commands it does. `man parted` should have some good explanations too...

Comment: @schmiddl I tried following `gparted` myself, it didn't show the exact `parted` commands, but did describe what it does, so I filled in some blanks

Comment: Great, works like a charm, thank you so much! There is one more thing: It won't mount automatically. What I did was make a directory in the /media/ folder and manually mount it in the terminal. Is there a terminal command to make the partition mount automatically when I plug the usb stick into the computer?

Comment: The different desktop environments can do their "own thing" with removable media, in XFCE it's Settings has a "Removable Drives and Media" where you can tell it to mount/browse/autorun when inserted or "hot-plugged". Unity should have similar settings somewhere. I think many use `udisks`/`udisksd`, and most file managers have a "disks" listing where you can click-to-mount. Or a program like Disks (gnome-disk-utility) usually works for browsing partitions & mounting/unmounting.

Comment: You are right, a restart of Ubuntu solved it. Now all USB stick automount again.